# Python Paramiko get_transport() and open_session() functions explanation

Tags: python, session, ssh, tcp, paramiko

If I use this code (of course after connecting to the ssh server):

```
client = client.get_transport().open_session()
```

I literally can't find proper information on `get_transport()` (not even in the documentation), but I expect it to return a socket (tcp) object, if that's true, what does `open_session()` do?
The documentation says the following:

> Request a new channel to the server, of type "session".  This is just
> an alias for calling open_channel with an argument of "session".

This is not quite clear to me, what is meant with "a new channel to the server of type session" and can someone explain to me what both functions actually do?

Answer (score 2):

SSH protocol has multiple layers.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Architecture

The "transport" layer is the lowest layer. But it's still above TCP, so above Python's `Socket`. And I believe that in Paramiko, the `Transport` class actually implements both the "transport" layer and the "user authentication" layer. As such, it is responsible for creating the "connection" layer, aka the sessions and channels.